# Stepper width won't resize properly in Xamarin Forms Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, resizable, stepper

I want to use a Stepper in my Xamarin Forms Project, but it won't resize the width properly in Android. The WithRequest won't work at all an when I set the margin it only resize one of the two buttons, the other one is still at its normal size.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width=".3*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width=".2*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    ...
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
...
<Stepper Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20,0,20,0"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to use a Stepper in my Xamarin Forms Project, but it won't resize the width properly in Android. The WithRequest wont work at all an when I set the margin it only resize one of the two buttons, the other one is still at it's normal size.

The buttons' sizes are not set according to the `WidthRequest` property. If you want to set the buttons' size, you'll have to make your own Stepper Control.

Make a few changes to the source codes of [StepperRenderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/StepperRenderer.cs)'s `OnElementChange` method will make it work for your own custom control. Following is the modified version of `StepperRenderer`:

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(MyStepper),typeof(MyStepperRenderer))]
namespace StepperDemo.Droid
{
    public class MyStepperRenderer : ViewRenderer<Stepper, LinearLayout>
    {
        AButton _downButton;
        AButton _upButton;

        public MyStepperRenderer()
        {
            AutoPackage = false;
        }

        protected override LinearLayout CreateNativeControl()
        {
            return new LinearLayout(Context) {

                Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
            };
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Stepper> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                _downButton = new AButton(Context) { Text = "-", Gravity = GravityFlags.Center, Tag = this };
                //Set the MinWidth of Button
                _downButton.SetMinWidth(50);

                _downButton.SetOnClickListener(StepperListener.Instance);

                _upButton = new AButton(Context) { Text = "+", Tag = this };
                _upButton.SetOnClickListener(StepperListener.Instance);
                //Set the MinWidth of Button
                _upButton.SetMinWidth(50);

                if (e.NewElement != null)
                {
                    //Set the Width and Height of the button according to the WidthRequest
                    _downButton.LayoutParameters = new LayoutParams((int)e.NewElement.WidthRequest, LayoutParams.MatchParent);
                    _upButton.LayoutParameters = new LayoutParams((int)e.NewElement.WidthRequest, LayoutParams.MatchParent);
                }

                var layout = CreateNativeControl();

                layout.AddView(_downButton);
                layout.AddView(_upButton);

                SetNativeControl(layout);
            }

            UpdateButtonEnabled();
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            switch (e.PropertyName)
            {
                case "Minimum":
                    UpdateButtonEnabled();
                    break;
               case "Maximum":
                    UpdateButtonEnabled();
                    break;
                case "Value":
                    UpdateButtonEnabled();
                    break;
                case "IsEnabled":
                    UpdateButtonEnabled();
                    break;
            }
        }

        void UpdateButtonEnabled()
        {
            Stepper view = Element;
            _upButton.Enabled = view.IsEnabled ? view.Value < view.Maximum : view.IsEnabled;
            _downButton.Enabled = view.IsEnabled ? view.Value > view.Minimum : view.IsEnabled;
        }

        class StepperListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnClickListener
        {
            public static readonly StepperListener Instance = new StepperListener();

            public void OnClick(global::Android.Views.View v)
            {
                var renderer = v.Tag as MyStepperRenderer;
                if (renderer == null)
                    return;

                Stepper stepper = renderer.Element;
                if (stepper == null)
                    return;

                if (v == renderer._upButton)
                    ((IElementController)stepper).SetValueFromRenderer(Stepper.ValueProperty, stepper.Value + stepper.Increment);
                else if (v == renderer._downButton)
                    ((IElementController)stepper).SetValueFromRenderer(Stepper.ValueProperty, stepper.Value - stepper.Increment);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use this renderer according to the [CustomRenderer Tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/introduction/).

And the Stepper Buttons' width will change properly:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple custom renderer like the following is enough to let the `Stepper` control honor the `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest` parameters:

```cs
using Android.Content;
using Android.Widget;
using MyApp.CustomRenderers;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using AButton = Android.Widget.Button;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Stepper), typeof(ResizableStepperRenderer))]

namespace MyApp.CustomRenderers;

public class ResizableStepperRenderer : StepperRenderer
{
    public ResizableStepperRenderer(Context context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
        
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Stepper> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement is not null &&
            Control is { } linearLayout)
        {
            if (linearLayout.GetChildAt(0) is AButton downButton)
            {
                downButton.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MatchParent,
                    LayoutParams.MatchParent,
                    0.5f);
            }
                
            if (linearLayout.GetChildAt(1) is AButton upButton)
            {
                upButton.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MatchParent,
                    LayoutParams.MatchParent,
                    0.5f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can be used as follows:

```xml
<Stepper
    WidthRequest="100"
    HeightRequest="40"
    Minimum="0"
    Maximum="99"
    Increment="1"
    Value="{Binding ... }" />
```